# String concatenation does not work in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, string, operators, concatenation

I am trying to execute a SQlite replace function, but use another field in the function.

```
select  locationname + '<p>' from location;
```

In this snip, the result is a list of 0s. I would have expected   a string with the text from locationname and the `'<p>'` literals.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Try using `||` in place of `+`

```
select  locationname || '<p>' from location;
```

From [**SQLite documentation**](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The || operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings of its operands.

Comment: field1 || field2 returns null if one of the fields is null.  One might want to do ifnull(field1,'')||ifnull(field2,''). That will give you a response if one or both fields are null. Then you get to figure out what you want to do if both were null.

Comment: @TomCerul or use `COALESCE(nullable_field, '') || COALESCE(another_nullable_field, '')`

Comment: The importance of TomCerul's comment  is worthy rewriting or at least editing the correct answer.

Answer (score 42):

The `||` operator is the concatenation in SQLite. Use this code:

```
select  locationname || '<p>' from location;
```

Comment: The double pipe is also the ANSI method of concatenating strings, supported on Oracle & PostgreSQL too...

Answer (score 37):

For comparison,

```
SQLite                      ||  
Oracle                      CONCAT(string1, string2) or ||
MySQL                       CONCAT(string1, string2, string3...) or || if PIPES_AS_CONCAT enabled
Postgres                    CONCAT(string1, string2, string3...) or ||
Microsoft SQL Server 2012+  CONCAT(string1, string2, string3...) or + 
Microsoft Access            +
```

Comment: Starting in 2012, SQL Server also supports `CONCAT(string1, string2, string3...)`

Comment: MySQL also supports `||` if `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` mode is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

for Visual Studio 2010, using the Data Sources designer or wizard, you're in trouble using || operator. Create a view in the sqlite db and create your data source(s) from that.

See also [this thread](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/1797/10869.aspx#10869).

Answer (score 0):

SQLite 3.44.0 and newer supports [CONCAT](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_corefunc.html#concat) function:

> concat(X,...)
>
> The concat(...) function returns a string which is the concatenation of the string representation of all of its non-NULL arguments. If all arguments are NULL, then concat() returns an empty string.

---

Query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(locationname, '<p>') 
FROM location;
```