# How to concat columns in Android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Can I concat two or more columns in Android sqlite ?
eg `select columna++ columnb as columnc from table`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3568779/2291

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `select columna || columnb as columnc from table`.

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(264): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'TITLE || BEGIN as BLABLA' does not exist

Comment: Not sure why you are having problems: `Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT *, \""+ KEY_NAME + "\" || \""+KEY_DESC + "\" AS val FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE_LOGS + " ORDER BY " + order, null);` works for me. I can extract the `val` column from the resulting cursor. You might need to escape the columns as I did above (using double quotes).