# SQLite joining two columns together in select results

Tags: android, sqlite

Is their a reason I cannot do

```
Select Firstname + Lastname
from Person
```

When using SQLite? does it not support this joining of columns... this is what i need for a view i am creating for a android project

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932147/how-to-concat-columns-in-android-sqlite

Comment: if I had remembered the word "Concat" i might have found that in my search! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Firstname || Lastname from Person
```

is what you are looking for ...

Comment: my hero.... is this just a SQLite thing or is it standard sql and im stuck in the mind of MSsql?

Comment: The only other one I know is MySQL and it is different (uses CONCAT)