# Does Dapper support the like operator?

Tags: sql, dapper

Using Dapper-dot-net...

The following yields no results in the data object:

```
var data = conn.Query(@"
    select top 25 
    Term as Label, 
    Type, 
    ID 
    from SearchTerms 
    WHERE Term like '%@T%'", 
    new { T = (string)term });
```

However, when I just use a regular String Format like:

```
string QueryString = String.Format("select top 25 Term as Label, Type, ID from SearchTerms WHERE Term like '%{0}%'", term);
var data = conn.Query(QueryString);
```

I get 25 rows back in the collection.  Is Dapper not correctly parsing the end of the parameter `@T`?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try:

```
term = "whateverterm";
var encodeForLike = term => term.Replace("[", "[[]").Replace("%", "[%]");

string term = "%" + encodeForLike(term) + "%";
var data = conn.Query(@"
   select top 25 
  Term as Label, 
  Type, 
  ID 
  from SearchTerms 
  WHERE Term like @term", 
  new { term });
```

There is nothing special about like operators, you never want your params inside string literals, they will not work, instead they will be interpreted as a string.

**note**

The hard-coded example in your second snippet is strongly discouraged, besides being a huge problem with sql injection, it can cause dapper to leak.

**caveat**

Any `like` match that is leading with a wildcard is not SARGable, which means it is slow and will require an index scan.

Comment: Sam - trying to get your answer to work in my project, but throwing errors.  why do you set the "term" before declaring it as a string?  I only need the % on the right side of the term in the query.  I tried doing: string formattedTerm = searchTerm + "[[]%[]]";  but it is not returning results.

Comment: Sam - might be worth answering him.  This has confused me as well

Comment: .Replace("[", "[[]").Replace("]","[]]") - this is wrong. 
Make sure you escape your like clause though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause

Comment: Note: this is approach is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, check Atir's answer for a better approach

Comment: For anyone (like) me, who didn't knew about "**SARGable**", [here is an explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Answer (score 68):

Yes it does. This simple solution has worked for me everytime:

```
db.Query<Remitente>("SELECT * 
                     FROM Remitentes 
                     WHERE Nombre LIKE @n", new { n = "%" + nombre + "%" })
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: This is the answer i liked best...simple and straight forward

Comment: This is my favorite for sure - I use string interpolation as well so it becomes ...   new { n = $"%{nombre}%" }

Comment: perfect! Made ext method out of it

Comment: should be the accepted answer

Comment: Why this one isn't accepted answer?

Answer (score 63):

Best way to use this to add concat function in query as it save in sql injecting as well, but concat function is only support above than sql 2012

```
string query = "SELECT * from country WHERE Name LIKE CONCAT('%',@name,'%');"
var results = connection.query<country>(query, new {name});
```

Comment: You can also use '+' instead of CONCAT eg: 
"SELECT * from country WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%';"

Answer (score 9):

The answer from Sam wasn't working for me so after some testing I came up with using the [SQLite CONCAT equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568779/string-concatenation-does-not-work-in-sqlite) which seems to work:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Name LIKE '%' || @NAME || '%'";
var data = IEnumerable data = conn.Query(sql, new { NAME = Name });
```

Comment: This also works in IBM Db2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to digress on Sam's answer, here is how I created two helper methods to make searches a bit easier using the LIKE operator.

First, creating a method for generating a parameterized query, this method uses *dynamic*: , but creating a strongly typed generic method should be more desired in many cases where you want static typing instead of dynamic.

```cs
public static dynamic ParameterizedQuery(this IDbConnection connection, string sql, Dictionary<string, object> parametersDictionary)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sql))
    {
        return null;
    }
    string missingParameters = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in parametersDictionary)
    {
        if (!sql.Contains(item.Key))
        {
            missingParameters += $"Missing parameter: {item.Key}";
        }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(missingParameters))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Parameterized query failed. {missingParameters}");
    }
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters(parametersDictionary);
    return connection.Query(sql, parameters);
}
```

Then adding a method to create a Like search term that will work with Dapper.

```cs
public static string Like(string searchTerm)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
    {
        return null;
    }
    Func<string, string> encodeForLike = searchTerm => searchTerm.Replace("[", "[[]").Replace("%", "[%]");
    return $"%{encodeForLike(searchTerm)}%";
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
var sql = $"select * from products where ProductName like @ProdName";
var herringsInNorthwindDb = connection.ParameterizedQuery(sql, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@ProdName", Like("sild") } });

foreach (var herring in herringsInNorthwindDb)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{herring.ProductName}");
}
```

And we get our sample data from Northwind DB:
[image: Sample data]

I like this approach, since we get helper extension methods to do repetitive work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution simple to this problem :

```
parameter.Add("@nomeCliente", dfNomeCliPesquisa.Text.ToUpper());

query = "SELECT * FROM cadastrocliente WHERE upper(nome) LIKE " + "'%" + dfNomeCliPesquisa.Text.ToUpper() + "%'";
```