# How do I do a like with parameters?

Tags: .net, mysql, database, ado.net, dapper

Here is a made up query

```
"select * from tbl where name like '@foo%'"
...
cmd.addparam(foo, bar) //not actual code
```

I get 0 results. I tried changing the where to `name like @foo` and wrote bar+"%" however i suspect that is incorrect (it should escape %?) and i got 0 rows yet again.

How do I like with parameters? My code actually uses dapper.net with mysql as its database.

Comment: Take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030099/does-dapper-support-the-like-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct your query as follows:

```
"select * from tbl where name like @foo"
```

then

```
cmd.addParam("@foo", bar + "%")
```

Comment: ok so i was using the right code however i discover that when doing `/a%` it doesnt find my `/ab` strings. It looks like it doesnt like starting with `/`

Comment: @acidzombie24 no, your original code is looking for the literal starting "@foo"... Nothing to do with the value from the parameter

Comment: @MarcGravell: I see. I ended up going with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614291/how-do-i-escape-mysql-properly#comment18667746_13614291 is that correct? I believe it is.