# How to concatenate strings with padding in sqlite

Tags: string, sqlite, string-concatenation, leading-zero

I have three columns in an sqlite table:

```
    Column1    Column2    Column3
    A          1          1
    A          1          2
    A          12         2
    C          13         2
    B          11         2
```

I need to select `Column1-Column2-Column3` (e.g. `A-01-0001`). I want to pad each column with a `-`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3568779/2291

Answer (score 421, accepted):

> The `||` operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings of
>   its operands.

From http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

For padding, the seemingly-cheater way I've used is to start with your target string, say '0000', concatenate '0000423', then substr(result, -4, 4) for '0423'.

**Update:** Looks like there is no native implementation of "lpad" or "rpad" in SQLite, but you can follow along (basically what I proposed) here: http://verysimple.com/2010/01/12/sqlite-lpad-rpad-function/

```
-- the statement below is almost the same as
-- select lpad(mycolumn,'0',10) from mytable

select substr('0000000000' || mycolumn, -10, 10) from mytable

-- the statement below is almost the same as
-- select rpad(mycolumn,'0',10) from mytable

select substr(mycolumn || '0000000000', 1, 10) from mytable
```

Here's how it looks:

```
SELECT col1 || '-' || substr('00'||col2, -2, 2) || '-' || substr('0000'||col3, -4, 4)
```

it yields

```
"A-01-0001"
"A-01-0002"
"A-12-0002"
"C-13-0002"
"B-11-0002"
```

Comment: @Andrew - In general any scalar operation that involves NULL will yield NULL.  Your requirements may be met using `COALESCE(nullable_field, '') || COALESCE(another_nullable_field, '')`.

Answer (score 50):

[SQLite has a `printf` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) which does exactly that:

```
SELECT printf('%s-%.2d-%.4d', col1, col2, col3) FROM mytable
```

Comment: Query Error: no such function: printf Unable to execute statement
select printf('%s.%s', id, url ) from mytable limit 7.   My version is 3.8.2 2014-12-06.  What version are you using?

Comment: 3.8.3 "And there are other minor enhancements such as the addition of the printf() SQL function."

Answer (score 21):

Just one more line for @tofutim answer ... if you want custom field name for concatenated row ...

```
SELECT 
  (
    col1 || '-' || SUBSTR('00' || col2, -2, 2) | '-' || SUBSTR('0000' || col3, -4, 4)
  ) AS my_column 
FROM
  mytable;
```

Tested on [SQLite 3.8.8.3](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html), Thanks!