# select query in sql-light dont work for me in android

Tags: android

this code work for me:

```
SQL = "SELECT _id,Fname,Lname,Phone,Car,CarNum,PicNum from MEN order by Lname,Fname";
.
.
public void update_list(String NN) {
       c = db.rawQuery(NN, null);
       startManagingCursor(c);

       String[] from = new String[]{"_id","PicNum","Fname","Lname","Car","CarNum" };
       int[] to = new int[]{  R.id._id,R.id.MyPic,R.id.Fname ,R.id.Lname,R.id.Car,R.id.CarNum };
       SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.my_list, c, from, to);
       setListAdapter(notes);


setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_list, c, from,to) {
```

but if my query like this:

```
SQL = "SELECT _id,Fname + Lname as Fname,Lname,Phone,Car,CarNum,PicNum from MEN order by Lname,Fname";
```

i got 0 in the column Fname.

Comment: `Fname + Lname` tries to add both values as numbers. It will even try to interpret text as numbers if it can. See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html the *4.0 Operators* section. E.g. `'5' + 'Peter' = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using an incorrect concatenation operator. Refer to the question below.

[How to concatenate strings with padding in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415/how-can-we-concatenate-string-in-sqlite)