# Search query for (name or forename) and (name forname) and (forname name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Im beginner in rails and have some problems to improve my search query:

In the controller i call:

```
def index
 if params[:search]
  @persons = Person.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
 else
  @persons = Person.order("created_at DESC")
 end
end
```

And in the model i have:

```
 def self.search(query)
  where("name like ?", "%#{query}%")
 end
```

So actually i only filter name! Now i tried to improve it but it didnt worked out how i liked it, my aim is that a user can type in for example:

```
 John
 Smith
 Smith John
 John Smith
```

and it always should return `John Smith`. So how do i write such a long sql query? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This search method should work for you:

```
def self.search(query)
  return where('FALSE') if query.blank?

  conditions = []
  search_columns = [ :vorname, :nachname ]

  query.split(' ').each do |word|
    search_columns.each do |column|
      conditions << " lower(#{column}) LIKE lower(#{sanitize("%#{word}%")}) "
    end
  end

  conditions = conditions.join('OR')    
  self.where(conditions)
end
```

- This code **is secure**: `sanitizes` the strings before calling the SQL
- This code **is flexible**: you can very easily add more columns to search on
- This code **is flexible**: you can easily split on more than just space (`- / |` etc)
- This code **can be used for chain-scoping**
- This code is **case-insensitive**, will work with either `John Smith` or `JohN SMITh`

Don't hesitate to ask questions if needed!

Comment: I thinks thats the best code but somehow i get a error: `SQLite3::SQLException: near "ILIKE": syntax error: SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"  WHERE ( vorname ILIKE '%'emmanuel'%' OR nachname ILIKE '%'emmanuel'%' )`

Comment: I updated my answer @JohnSmith -- Also I recommend you to use English in your applications, its easier to maintain for other people and it is kind of a part of the Rails Naming Convention ;)

Comment: Sorry but somehow i get the same error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Patients#search ``SQLite3::SQLException: near "ILIKE": syntax error: SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"  WHERE ( vorname ILIKE '%Vera%' OR nachname ILIKE '%Vera%' )`

Comment: The problem was the ILIKE function (does not exist in SQLite3), I updated my answer in consequence @JohnSmith

Comment: Yes now it works! Thank you very much! You helped me a lot! I only have one more little thing! The code you gave me makes many single queries i mean for example `name LIKE Search`. But maybe it woulb be better to split your code into two parts the first part only get triggerd when one search param is given for example `John` or `Smith` and the there  could be another code that gets triggered when you submit two params like `John Smith` or `Smith John` and that looks if the two statements are like `name and forname`! I hope you understood me?

Comment: My problem is that i generated a large database and noticed that when i pass for example `John Smith` i get so many entries like 40 simths and 100 other people with forname john!

Comment: I started a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937318/better-search-query-for-two-columns-forename-and-name Maybe you can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

What about doing something like this?

```
def self.search(query)
  where("name LIKE ? or forename LIKE ? or concat(name, ', ', forename) LIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%" , "%#{query}%")
end
```

If your search queries are getting really complex you might want to take a look at search gems, such as [elasticsearch](https://rubygems.org/gems/elasticsearch)

Comment: I get a error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: concat:`

Comment: agh. I was assuming MySQL. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415/how-can-we-concatenate-string-in-sqlite in order to concatenate with Sqlite3. Having that said, I think @MrYoshiji answer should be the accepted one. Really nice solution

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work for the following search queries

```
John
Smith
John Smith
```

Do the following if you want it to work for reversed search queries also

```
def self.search(query)
  name_parts = query.split(' ')
  condition = name_parts.collect{|part| "name like #{sanitize("%#{part}%")}"}.join(' AND ')
  where(condition)
 end
```

Comment: This code won't work for searches like `"pierre's car"` -> it will break the SQL query because of the quote ' ; Also the "AND" has no extra space and the SQL will look like this: `"name like '%whtvr%'ANDname like '%wtr%'ANDname ..."` -> won't work

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this one? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937318/better-search-query-for-two-columns-forename-and-name