# Better search query for two columns forename and name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

Actually i have this search query from MrJoshi here is the associated question:
[Search query for (name or forename) and (name forname) and (forname name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934616/search-query-for-name-or-forename-and-name-forname-and-forname-name)

```
def self.search(query)
  return where('FALSE') if query.blank?

  conditions = []
  search_columns = [ :forname, :name ]

  query.split(' ').each do |word|
    search_columns.each do |column|
      conditions << " lower(#{column}) LIKE lower(#{sanitize("%#{word}%")}) "
    end
  end

  conditions = conditions.join('OR')    
  self.where(conditions)
end
```

The problem with this search query is that it returns way to much records. For example if somebody is searching for `John Smith` this search query returns all records wih the `forename John` and all records with the `name Smith` although there is only one person that exactly matches the search query means `name is Smith and forename is John`
So i changed the code a little bit:

```
def self.search(query)
  return where('FALSE') if query.blank?

  conditions = []

  query2 = query.split(' ')

  if query2.length == 2
      conditions << " lower(:forname) AND lower(:name) LIKE ?', lower(#{sanitize("%#{query2.first}%")}) , lower(#{sanitize("%#{query2.last}%")})"
      conditions << " lower(:forname) AND lower(:name) LIKE ?', lower(#{sanitize("%#{query2.last}%")}) , lower(#{sanitize("%#{query2.first}%")})"
  else
    search_columns = [ :forname, :name ]
       query2.each do |word|
        search_columns.each do |column|
         conditions << " lower(#{column}) LIKE lower(#{sanitize("%#{word}%")}) "
        end
       end
  end

  conditions = conditions.join('OR')    
  self.where(conditions)
end
```

But now i get this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "', lower('": syntax error: SELECT  "patients".* FROM "patients"  WHERE ( lower(:forname) AND lower(:name) LIKE ?', lower('%John%') , lower('%Smith%')OR lower(:forname) AND lower(:name) LIKE ?', lower('%Smith%') , lower('%John%')) LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0
```

What did i wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You have an extra `'` right before `lower('%John%')`.

Comment: Sory but when i remove it i get a similar error. Im sure that my queries are in general not working: `lower(:forname) AND lower(:name) LIKE ?', lower(#{sanitize("%#{query2.first}%")}) , lower(#{sanitize("%#{query2.last}%")})`

Comment: Every character between `LIKE` and `lower` has to be removed ? (i.e. `<space>?',<space>` should just be a `<space>`)