# Having issues with LIKE operator in SQLLiteHelper class

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-like

I am using SQLLiteHelper class to do the database calls in android. I have below code in which basically I am trying to find any instance of old comment and replace with new comment. If I remove single quotes after LIKE then I get this message.

```
(1) near "%": syntax error
```

If I keep the single quotes then I get following message. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
Too many bind arguments.  2 arguments were provided but the statement needs 1 arguments.
```

```
public int updateComment(String oldComment, String newComment)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CommentEntry.COLUMN_NAME_COMMENT, newComment);
String selection = CommentEntry.COLUMN_NAME_COMMENT + " LIKE '%?%'";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ oldComment };
        int count = database.update(CommentEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did find a bug report from 2013 that might be related: [Android 56062](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56062). If that's an issue, here, you can bypass `update()` and run the query directly without a convenience method.

In the meantime, there's a syntax problem with your query. Bind values with a `LIKE` clause are tricky. A `?` in quotes is just a literal question mark.

```
WHERE foo LIKE '%?%'
```

The above is just a search for any `foo` containing a question mark:

```
WHERE foo LIKE ?
```

The above allows you to pass in the wildcards as part of the bind param: `%sometext%`.

I think that's a little ugly, though. If we know that we're always going to search with wildcards, I'd want to use [concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415/how-can-we-concatenate-string-in-sqlite):

```
WHERE foo LIKE '%' || ? || '%'
```

As an aside, I hope you realize that [a query with leading and trailing wildcards can be very expensive](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/).

Comment: Thanks @rutter it really helped. Indeed it was really tricky.