# concatenate values from two columns and compare it against one value in sqlite

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite

I am using sqlite in one my ios project where among other columns there are two columns.  one has country code for mobile dialing like +880 and other column has rest of the mobile number like 1912353697. Now i want to join values from these   two columns and compare the result value  against like +8801912353697 and if matches pull the corresponding name value in that table . what would be the right query. I have tried like `SELECT name FROM CONTACT_LIST WHERE   (SELECT mblDc || mbl FROM CONTACT_LIST) = "+8801617634317"  ;` but that does not work .

A help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Any error messages or is the result just incorrect?

Comment: the corresponding name does not show up. result  show all the value from name column @EnricoSusatyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT name FROM CONTACT_LIST 
WHERE mblDc || mbl = "+8801617634317";
```

From [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html): `The || operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings of its operands.`

Answer (score 0):

please check
[How to concatenate strings with padding in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415/how-can-we-concatenate-string-in-sqlite)

using substr function we can do the job and the query should be like

```
SELECT name FROM CONTACT_LIST WHERE  (mblDc || mbl) = "+8801617634317" ;
```