# Using the LIKE Operator: Works With SQL Server but not SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, t-sql

My application is one that retrieves data online when it is connected to the internet, but allows the user to view the data when offline. To achieve this, I have the app download pertinent information from the online SQL server and save it to a SQLite DB for use when the machine is not connected to the internet. On one of my windows, I have a search function that finds "notes" that have the entered string. So first I wrote the query for when it is connected to the SQL database:

```
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring);
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                string sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM " + Application.Current.Properties["connection"] + "_Notes WHERE Written_ID = @uid AND Content LIKE '%' + @srch + '%' ORDER BY Creation_Time DESC";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstr, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uid", Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Properties["userid"].ToString()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("srch", searchbox.Text.ToString());
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Notes");
                sda.Fill(dt);
                notescontrol.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                conn.Close();
```

So this does exactly what I want it to do. It returns all the notes that have that string. Next I created the string for the SQLite DB (this database has an [Office] column that needs to match the user's current column):

```
                SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(mysqliteconnstring);
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                string sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE Office = @off AND Written_ID = @uid AND Content LIKE '%' + @srch + '%' ORDER BY Creation_Time DESC";
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlstr, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("off", Application.Current.Properties["connection"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uid", Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Properties["userid"].ToString()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("srch", searchbox.Text.ToString());
                SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Notes");
                sda.Fill(dt);
                notescontrol.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                conn.Close();
```

I did my own research and I did not find that there were any differences pertaining to the like statement  in SQL vs SQLite. So where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The concatenation is different in SQL Server and SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415/how-can-we-concatenate-string-in-sqlite) the string concatenation operator in SQLite is `||`. So you need two different query texts. But you could avoid this problem if you change the way in which you pass the parameter for the LIKE condition

```
 string sqlstr = @"SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE Office = @off 
                     AND Written_ID = @uid 
                     AND Content LIKE @srch 
                     ORDER BY Creation_Time DESC";

 ....

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@srch", "%" + searchbox.Text + "%");
```

By the way, the searchbox.Text property is already a string, no need to call ToString() on it.