# how to write a sql query to search a sub string in column and the sub string is a variable

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have written an sqlite3 query to execute the below,

```
cur.execute("select * from table where column like '%s'"% (variable1))
```

which gives the strings the completely match with the variable1.
But I want an sqlite3 query that can show:

```
cur.execute("select * from table where column *contains* '%s'"% (variable1))
```

What query should I write find any string that contains 'variable1'.
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Which dbms are you using of those 3? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: And what is the issue?  The second statement is missing the closing double quote, but other than that, why doesn't it work?

Comment: I am using sqlite3 database. closed the double quotes, still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

See, **LIKE** functionality is simple.

If you want to **search a string**, you will have to place it in single quotes:

*search all names starting with s*

```
select name from names where name like 's%';
```

*search all names ending with s*

```
select name from names where name like '%s';
```

*search all names that contain s*

```
select name from names where name like '%s%';
```

But if you have stored your string in a variable **var**

You just have to do this:

```
select name from names where name like var;
```

Comment: what can i write for 
select name from names where name like %var.
that is all names that ends with the variable.

Comment: @Nitya - select * from train where name like concat('%',@var,'%');

Comment: @Nitya - Which database are you using?

Comment: @Nitya - Try searching Google. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415/how-to-concatenate-strings-with-padding-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

To ignore characters, you have to put percent signs into the LIKE pattern (and double them so that the `%` operator does not try to replace them):

```
cur.execute("select * from table where column like '%%%s%%'" % (variable1))
```

But direct string interpolation brings formatting problems and possibly SQL injections. Better use a parameter:

```
cur.execute("select * from table where column like ?", ['%' + variable1 + '%'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try

cur.execute("""select * from table where column like '%{}%' """.format(variable))

Refer this link for sql

[SQL SELECT WHERE field contains words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words)