# SQLite. How to merge two cases in just one column, from a SQL Case function?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite.

I have this query:

```
    SELECT Customer.contract_number,
       Customer.name,
       Customer.last,
       Customer.phone,
       Contrato.desc,

       CASE Contract.sinc WHEN 1 THEN 'Sincro' ELSE 'NO sincro' END Status1,
       CASE Customer.rev WHEN 1 THEN 'Rev' ELSE 'No rev' END Status2

  FROM Customer,
       Contract
 WHERE Customer.contract_number = Contract.contract_number
UNION ALL
SELECT HandCo.contract_number,
       HandCo.name,
       HandCo.last,
       HandCo.phone,
       HandCo.des,

       CASE HandCon.tradit WHEN 1 THEN 'Tradit' ELSE NULL END Status3

  FROM HandContract;
```

I want  to merge the result from Status1 and result from Status2 in just one column.
How I do that? Thank you.

I'm using a UNION for the query and that is the reason why I want to merge the Case Funtion.

Thank you for respond.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just concatenate the two `CASE` statements?

Comment: What do you mean with "merge"? Please provide some sample data and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings with || in sqllite.

```
SELECT Customer.contract_number, Customer.name, Customer.last, Customer.phone, Contract.desc,

   CASE Contract.sinc WHEN 1 THEN 'Sincro' ELSE 'No sincro' END
   ||
   CASE Customer.rev WHEN 1 THEN 'Rev' ELSE 'No Rev' END Status
FROM 
    Customer, Contract;
```

Similar topic: [How to concatenate strings with padding in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415/how-to-concatenate-strings-with-padding-in-sqlite)

Comment: Well, I'm a little bit newbie here, I'm not explained it well.

This is my full query:

Comment: SELECT Customer.contract_number,
       Customer.name,
       Customer.last,
       Customer.phone,
       Contrato.desc,

       CASE Contract.sinc WHEN 1 THEN 'Sincro' ELSE 'NO sincro' END Status1,
       CASE Customer.rev WHEN 1 THEN 'Rev' ELSE 'No rev' END Status2

  FROM Customer,
       Contract
 WHERE Customer.contract_number = Contract.contract_number
UNION ALL
SELECT HandCo.contract_number,
       HandCo.name,
       HandCo.last,
       HandCo.phone,
       HandCo.des,

       CASE HandCon.tradit WHEN 1 THEN 'Tradit' ELSE NULL END Status3

  FROM HandContract;

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with string concatenation?

```
SELECT cu.contract_number, cu.name, cu.last, cu.phone, co.desc,
       ((CASE co.sinc WHEN 1 THEN 'Sincro' ELSE 'No sincro' END) || '-' ||
        (CASE cu.rev WHEN 1 THEN 'Rev' ELSE 'No Rev' END)
       ) as Status
FROM Customer cu JOIN
     Contract co
     ON co.?? = cu.??;
```

Note:  I removed the `,` from the `FROM` clause.  I really doubt that is the intention of this query.  You need to put the proper `JOIN` condition in the `ON` clause, replacing the `??` with the appropriate column names.