# SQLite3 - How to select a specific number from a string

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table named `shoes`:

```
Shoe_model     price    sizes
-----------------------------------------------
Adidas KD      $55      '8, 9, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5'

Nike Tempo     $56      '8, 9, 11.5'

Adidas XL      $30.99   '9, 10, 11, 13'
```

How can I select a row for a specific size?

My attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE sizes = '10';
```

Is there a way around this? Using `LIKE` will get you both 10 and 10.5 sizes so I'm trying to use `WHERE` for this. Thanks

Comment: use `sizes like '%10,%' or right(sizes,2)='10'`. You will be better off normalizing your data

Comment: or use `CONCAT(sizes,',') like  '%10,%'`

Comment: I'm getting `no such function: CONCAT`

Comment: My code: `SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE CONCAT(sizes,',') like '%10,%'`

Comment: quick google search for "sqlite concat" finds this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415/how-to-concatenate-strings-with-padding-in-sqlite. Basically, it is `||` operator, like in Oracle, Postgres

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not be storing the sizes as a comma delimited string.  You should have a separate row with one row per size per show.  That is the SQLish way to store things.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  In you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM shoes
WHERE ',' || '10' || ',' LIKE '%,' || sizes || ',%';
```

The delimiters are important so "10" doesn't match "100".