# How to update sqlite row with concatenate existing values in row with a new value

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite, insert-update

I would like to add a value (concatenate) at the end of existing values in a column of sqlite table. 
ie: the column contains : banana, orange, pear, pinapple
I want to add lemon at the end of the column to have : banana, orange, pear, pinapple, lemon

Answer (score 2):

Use the concatenation operator `||` in the `update` statement:

```
update tablename
set columnname = columnname || ', lemon'
where columnname = 'banana, orange, pear, pinapple'
```

or:

```
where <some other condition>
```

Replace `tablename` and `columnname` with your table's and column's names.
If you want to update all the rows of the table remove the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Is perhaps [this answer here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415/how-to-concatenate-strings-with-padding-in-sqlite) the right one?

So in a table "groceries" with a column fruits "banana, orange" like

```
SELECT fruits || ', lemon' FROM groceries
```

this would yield

```
banana, orange, lemon
```

Comment: My question was not clear :( ...I updated it by replacing "row" with "column".
The column contains : banana, orange, pear, pinapple and I want to add lemon at the end