# How can i combine my sequence number in a single row

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm having trouble on combining sequence numbers in sqlite to android

i tried trim but I'm trouble understanding the output and how to set it correctly

1st table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Plans" (
    "plans_id"  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "cycle_set_id"  INTEGER,
    "cycle_number"  INTEGER,
    "status"    TEXT,
    "status_date"   TEXT,
    "created_at"    TEXT,
    "updated_at"    TEXT,
    "deleted_at"    TEXT
);
```

2nd table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Settings" (
    "id"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "settings_id"   INTEGER,
    "warehouseID"   INTEGER,
    "code"  TEXT,
    "value" TEXT,
    "created_at"    TEXT,
    "updated_at"    TEXT,
    "deleted_at"    TEXT
);
```

if plans_id(1st table) value is 1 
and warehouseID(2nd table) value is 1000

how can i get this result = 10001?

Comment: Have you tried parsing the values to string then do concatenation?

Comment: no i haven't tried it yet but in my understanding is concat only works on string??

Comment: I am getting trouble to understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: @rainerregalendez that is why you should parse the `id`'s to string first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate strings with padding in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134415/how-to-concatenate-strings-with-padding-in-sqlite)