# PHP - Issue with PDO using CONCAT() with SQLite

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, pdo

I'm using the same query, through PDO connector, to concatenate string in both:
MySQL database and a mirroring SQLite one.
Both they have same table same structure etc.

But when the query is executed, MySQL performs the query correctly, while SQLite goes in error thus I get an error 500.

Is there a solution to have it working for both databases please?
Here down below the parameterized Query I use.

As I said:
Without the line  `` `IP` = CONCAT(IP, :param3) ``, everything is working fine (on MySQL as well as SQLite)

With the line  `` `IP` = CONCAT(IP, :param3) ``, MySQL is correctly concatenated, SQLite crashes

```
$query = "UPDATE downloaded SET
    `player` = player + 1,
    `when` = :param0,
    `IP` = CONCAT(IP, :param3)
    WHERE who = :param1 AND what = :param2";

$params = array(
    ':param0' => $when_,
    ':param1' => $Email,
    ':param2' => $file,
    ':param3' => $IP_Caller . "<br />"
);
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not support the function `CONCAT()`.
You will have to use the operator `||`:

```
`IP` = IP || :param3
```

If you want to use the same code in MySql too, you will have to enable the [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) mode. This mode is by default disabled so the operator `||` is just an alias for the logical `OR`.

Comment: Also if you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37811056/1213708, *MySQL also supports || if PIPES_AS_CONCAT mode is enabled*

Comment: In this case SQLite is correctly  concatenated.
But MySQL substitutes the inner value, with 1.

Comment: @TormyVanCool if you want to use the same code in MySql too, you will have to enable the PIPES_AS_CONCAT mode: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat Thir mode is by default disabled so the operator `||` is just an alias for the logical `OR`.