# SQL query in R using concatenation methods

Tags: sql, r, concatenation

I tried using this query below in concatenation that I found in this forum as well:

```
DataFrame <- sqldf("select FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, FirstName || ' ' || MiddleName || ' ' || LastName as FullName from People")
```

Unfortunately if for example, MiddleName has no data or NA in the row, FullName also becomes NA despite the fact there is a LastName and FirstName. Same goes with the other columns.

Comment: I can replicate the `NA` issue, but a blank field for MiddleName `""` seems to work okay - e.g., using `People <- data.frame(
  FirstName=c("Joe","Dave", "John"),
  MiddleName=c(NA,"Alan", ""),
  LastName=c("Bloggs","Davies","Smith")
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealing from this previous comment here - [String concatenation does not work in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568779/string-concatenation-does-not-work-in-sqlite#comment9329851_3568822) - this is really an *SQLite* issue, rather than an *sqldf* issue.

Since `NULL || "text"` returns `NULL` but `'' || "text"` returns `''` you need to replace with blank text using `coalesce()` or `ifnull()`:

```
library(sqldf)

People <- data.frame(
  FirstName=c("Joe","Dave", "John"),
  MiddleName=c(NA,"Alan", ""),
  LastName=c("Bloggs","Davies","Smith")
)


sqldf("
  select
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    MiddleName,
    FirstName || ' ' || MiddleName || ' ' || LastName as FullName,
    FirstName || ' ' || coalesce(MiddleName,'') || ' ' || coalesce(LastName,'') as FullFix
  from People
")

#  FirstName LastName MiddleName         FullName          FullFix
#1       Joe   Bloggs       <NA>             <NA>      Joe  Bloggs
#2      Dave   Davies       Alan Dave Alan Davies Dave Alan Davies
#3      John    Smith                 John  Smith      John  Smith
```

Comment: Ohh I guess I need to search more lol. Thanks!